# routerLink doesn't navigate to lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I have a problem with navigating to the component defined in a lazy loading module.
The component `ListComponent` is defined under the path "test" (*my-routing.module.ts* - lazy loading module). Whenever I click on the Test button (*test.component.html*) I get the exception:

> NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'.

Why?

My *app-routing.module.ts* looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.gard';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';


const myModule = () => import('./my-routing/my-.module').then(x => x.MyRoutingModule);
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'experiment', loadChildren: myModule },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My *my-routing.module.ts* is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListComponent } from '../list.component';
import { TestComponent } from '../test/test.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'test', component: ListComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

My *test.component.html* looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-1">
      <a [routerLink]="['test']"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Test</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your *app.routing.ts*,

```
{ path: 'experiment', loadChildren: myModule },
```

All the routes in the `MyRoutingModule` will start with path: "experiment/".

Hence, change the path "test" to "experiment/test".

```
<a [routerLink]="['experiment/test']">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Test
    </button>
</a>
```

Note that you can apply the `[routerLink]` attribute to the `<button>` element without needing the `<a>` element.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['experiment/test']">
    Test
</button>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gkeesw?file=src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts)

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong, but I am getting still `NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment`. I see your app on stack blitz works perfectly though.

Comment: Is your issue solved? Which URL path has the mentioned error?

Comment: It works. My silly mistake with the importing my-routing.module.ts. Its all good. Thank you very much